# image was not uploaded. Disallowed File Type. in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I am working in Magento 2.3.3 and 
when I add/edit product from admin in Magento 2 and trying to upload PNG and JPG image then I get an error message:

> image was not uploaded. Disallowed File Type.

I set permission to 777 to pub/static folder but not getting success.

Here is the [sceenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OA0fC.png)

How can I upload images?

Comment: Can you please try image without underscore and without spaces and retry ?

Comment: yes i have upload image without underscore and without spaces but not get success.

Comment: Also its working on my local environment but not on the server

Comment: @sandeep any solution found?

Answer (score 0):

magento version 2.3
Solution is editing,

`if ($uploader->checkMimeType($this->getAllowedMimeTypes())) {`

to

`if (!$uploader->checkMimeType($this->getAllowedMimeTypes())) {`

in `magento/module-catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/Gallery/Upload.php` core file

Answer (score -1):

I'm also faced the same problem..

Problem has solved let me share solution hare

there was no any problem with any permission. I have just changed a code in uploader.php folder

went to  directory :  **public_html/vendor/magento/framework/File/uploader.php**

and replace a line in uploader.php : ( **return $this->fileMime->getMimeType($this->_file['tmp_name']);** )with ( **return $this->_file['type'];** )

Now my image upload in working fine

Try this maybe this work for you.

Comment: it is not advised to change magento source files and also this didn't work for me. sorry